# TypeError when converting shapefiles to KMLs using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, shapefile, qgis-3, convert, kml

In QGIS 3.16 I'm trying to load all shapefiles from a folder and subfolders and export all to KMLs files in a single folder (The shapefiles have different names).

This error appears, but I don't understand what I can do to resolve this:

> ```
> TypeError: QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat():
> arguments did not match any overloaded call:
>   overload 1: argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'
>   overload 2: argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'
>   overload 3: argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'
> ```

And the code is:

```py
import os
    
input_folder = 'D:\python_dados_av1'
output_folder = 'D:\teste'
    
layers = [] 
for root, folder, files in os.walk(input_folder):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.shp'):
            fullname = os.path.join(root, file)
            rename_shp = 'convert_%s' % (file)
            newfile = os.path.join(output_folder,rename_shp)
            layers.append(QgsVectorLayer(fullname, file.split('.')[0]))
            QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(file, newfile, "utf-8", "KML")
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Vector/QgsVectorFileWriter.html#qgis.core.QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat) the first argument should be a `QgsVectorLayer`, which is why you are getting the `unexpected type` error.

You are also missing the `QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem` parameter.

This should work:

```py
import os

layers = [] 
for root, folder, files in os.walk(input_folder):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.shp'):
            fullname = os.path.join(root, file)
            rename_shp = 'convert_%s' % (file)
            newfile = os.path.join(output_folder,rename_shp)

            # assign the QgsVectorLayer you make to a variable which you can then pass to the QgsVectorFileWriter
            tmp_lyr = QgsVectorLayer(fullname, file.split('.')[0])
            layers.append(tmp_lyr)
            
            # get the CRS from the layer
            crs = tmp_lyr.crs()  
            QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(tmp_lyr, newfile, "utf-8", crs, "KML")
```